# Getting the following error upon exceuting the below code: Index out of range

Tags: python, file, syntax-error

```
def evolve():
    global pop,fvals
    for g in xrange(0,gmax):     
        for i in xrange(0,NP):           
            while 1:
                r1=random.randint(0,NP-1)
                if r1!=i:          
                    break           
            while 1:
                r2=random.randint(0,NP-1)
                if r2!=r1 and r2!=i:
                    break
            while 1:
                r3=random.randint(0,NP-1)
                if r3!=r2 and r3!=r1 and r3!=i:
                    break
            U=[]
            V=[]
            for j in xrange(0,dim):    
                   U.insert(j,(pop[r3])[j] + F*((pop[r1])[j]-(pop[r2])[j]))                     
            jrand = floor(int(rand1()*dim)) 
            for j in xrange(0,dim):
        if rand1()<=cr or j==jrand:
                     U.insert(j,(pop[r3])[j] + F*((pop[r1])[j]-(pop[r2])[j]))  
                else:
                     U.insert(j,(pop[i])[j])         
            V.insert(i,U)                         
        fvals2.insert(i,fun(U)) 
        x=open("x.out","w")         
        for i in xrange(NP):
            for j in xrange(dim):
               print i
           print j
               x.write(str((V[i])[j]) + '\t')
            x.write(str(fvals2[i]))
            x.write('\n')
```

While executing this code block shows an error:

```
x.write(str((V[i])[j]) + '\t')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here I have taken `gmax=5`, `dim=2` and `NP=5`.

Comment: The list `V` appears to have fewer than `NP` elements. Either change what `i` ranges over in that loop, or figure out why `V` has too few elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `V` to `[]` on each of your `for n in xrange(0,NP)` loops, losing any values it had previously. That means that by the time you're writing the file, `V` only has one value contained in it (at most), which is why you're getting an IndexError when you try to read `xrange(NP)` values out of it. You probably want to initialize `V` outside that loop.

You're also missing some indents on `if rand1()<=cr or j==rand`, but I'm guessing that happened when putting the code into your post or it probably wouldn't have ran far enough to get the IndexError when writing a file.

That aside, please consider the following:

1. Please name your variables with actual names - all these single letters and letter-number combinations make the code really hard to read.
2. You might also consider breaking some of these nested operations up into separate functions, which could also improve readability.
3. You aren't closing the output file after you're done writing it - you probably want to add an `x.close()` line to the end or do all the writing within an `with open('x.out','w') as x:` block. You're also overwriting that file on each of the loops of `for g in xrange(0,gmax)`, so you might want to move it outside that loop as well.